# Reading material for making the switch from FL to Reason

Tags: daw, studio, reason

my name's Daniel, I'm a busy student currently attempting to complete an Audio Engineering course. I have both FL Studio and Reason but I never touched Reason until now, since I'm learning so much about synthesis and whatnot... FL Studio is much more appealing to the eye and I own the FL Studio Bible which makes learning about the software fun and interesting but I've found, after toying around with Reason for some time, that the quality of my tracks I export from Reason are of MUCH better quality. I need a recommendation for books (can be multiple) or video tutorials for this software.

tl;dr I have the FL Studio Bible but I need something similar for Reason, like all-encompassing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think one of the best resources to learn Reason is the [Reason's operation manual itself](https://archive.org/details/Reason_7_Owners_Manual). It's free, in-depth, and made by the Reason producers. Other resources' relevance will depend on the Reason's current version and the literature that covers that version specifically. For example, the only third-party book that covers version 7 (the later version at the time of this answer) seems to be [this one](http://amzn.com/1285866576).

Propellerheads has its own [learning shop](https://shop.propellerheads.se/browse/?product_type=learning) and [micro tutorials](https://www.propellerheads.se/products/reason/?fuseaction=get_article&article=micro-tutorials) section.

A popular third-party Reason learning resource is [Reason Experts](http://www.reasonexperts.com/).

You might want to widen your scope and learn sound design and music production outside of the Reason context, learn about them in general. This way you can apply this knowledge in Reason, FL Studio, Logic, Cubase, Live, and any other DAW, synth, sampler, tool.

Reason-specific material might dive too much into Reason particulars and not so much into synthesis and production. And that's a good thing if you want to be a Reason guru, but you might be more interested in synthesis and production than in the Reason system. If that's the case, you might want to learn about them directly and specifically.

There is an excellent sound design synthesis course in Coursera: [Introduction to Sound Design.](https://www.coursera.org/course/digitalsounddesign) It's free, in-depth, with exams, forums, lectures, certification (not free), etc.

For general music production Berklee is offering a free [introductory course in music production](https://www.coursera.org/course/musicproduction) (through Coursera), that includes DAWs, effects, and even a little bit of sysnthesis. As the sound design course, this also includes lectures, forums, exams, certification (not free), etc.

Comment: As a precision, you can also watch the youtube tutorials made by BoyInABand. He made some 7days tutorials in almost every electronic genre, and they are really helpful, I learned how to use reason thanks to him.